# github: this branch is N commits behind

Tags: git, github

I forked another repo and made some changes, all on directly on the github site... I have no need to fetch a local copy (it's too big to fit onto my space-limited IDE) so I want to keep all actions done directly on the github repo page (there are unlikely to be many changes required, and if so they will be insignificant and easy to do via the github webpage).

Those changes have been merged by the owner of the other repo, so that our two repos are now synchronised.  However, my fork is now showing:

```
This branch is 4 commits behind OtherOne:master.
```

How do I fix things (purely via the github page) to get things to a state where my repo is not showing as being behind theirs?  If I do a `Compare` in my repo it says:

```
There isn’t anything to compare.
OtherOne:master is up to date with all commits from MyOne:master.  Try switching the base for your comparison.
```

So I think that the repos are in fact now fully synchronised... but I just want to remove that "behind" message (because I'm like that).  Is there any way?  I could just delete my repo and re-fork... but that seems inelegant.

And in future, if the other repo is updated, how do I pull those changes into mine... again... all on github and not via the CLI.

Comment: The github website is not made to do this. You'll need to make this change locally, and push it back to github. --- Also, what does your IDE has to do with git?

Comment: `what does your IDE has to do with git?` -- nothing except that I don't have sufficient space on my IDE to clone a 500MB repo just in order to change one line of code and push it back.  Seems more efficient to do it directly on github.

Comment: What if you didn't use the IDE to make the change? You could even do a shallow clone.

Comment: Not use the IDE... like what?  Deploy a (temporary or more permanent) cloud server for this?  It's precisely that extra hassle/cost that I want to avoid by editing directly on github... this repo is not under continual development and just the occasional tweak may be required.  And a shallow clone isn't going to help... even a depth of 1 is too large... the repo has some very big data files in it.

Comment: What I meant was, why not clone the repo to your local computer, sans IDE or cloud server, and then make the change there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: you can now perform this action via the GitHub frontend's `Fetch Upstream` button - [see the Release Notes here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-05-06-sync-an-out-of-date-branch-of-a-fork-from-the-web/):

> You can now use the web UI to synchronize an out of date branch of a fork with its upstream branch. If there are no merge conflicts between the branches, the fork's branch is updated either by fast-forwarding or by merging from the upstream's branch. If there are conflicts, you will be prompted to open a pull request to resolve.

[image: GitHub Fetch Upstream functionality]

Old Answer:

Create a pull request that merges `OtherOne:master` into your forked repo, then merge it. That should remove the message and ensure that the two repos are indeed synchronized.

Comment: Thanks... someone actually trying to help instead of just downvoting and criticizing my approach.  Full steps were: I went into my repo, clicked on New Pull Request, (says there is Nothing to Compare), click on switch the base to reverse the comparison so that my repo is on the left and the upstream repo on the right (with arrow pointing left into mine), now it says "Able to merge. These branches can be automatically merged", then click Create Pull Request, give it a title, click Create Pull Request again, then Merge Pull Request, and Confirm.

Comment: @drmrbrewer Interesting... I did neither.

Comment: @evolutionxbox hmm but "`The github website is not made to do this`" ... actually it seems that it *is* made to do this, and my approach of doing everything I need via the github website is a valid one... all I needed was a bit of a steer on using pull requests (available on the website).

Comment: Further note: even if "switch the base" isn't showing, you can switch them by manually editing the URL in the address bar.  Or change the left-hand drop down to your own repo (it will then say "there isn't anything to compare", then choose "compare across forks", then choose the other repo from the right hand drop down.. that puts your repo on the left and the other on the right

Comment: Great! It worked, but now it says `This branch is 1 commit ahead of dan-giddins:master.` And comparing shows the reason `Merge pull request #1 from dan-giddins/master`. Seems like an infinite cycle where the forks never will become even... What can I do?

Answer (score 26):

Don't try it with the github site (it's possible but a bad idea). Instead use the "clean" way and do this from inside the dir with your git-repo:

1. Tell your repository about the original one:

   `git remote add upstream git://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git`
2. Get the original branches: `git fetch upstream`
3. Pull in the original data in to your branch: `git pull upstream master`
4. Push this to your github repository: `git push`

Comment: @drmrbrewer, this should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: @DarkTemplar The OP explicitly wrote _"(purely via the github page)"_. ;)

Comment: As you can see from the answer above its possible. Explain why you say it is a bad idea.

Comment: it worked perfectly for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provide another approaching if the branch is not master:
(specifically if you clone only one branch repository to local using :

```
git clone -b branch-name git://github.com/YOUR_FORK_REPOSITORY.git
```

)

Using git command

```
git checkout -b upstream-branch-name branch-name
git pull git://github.com/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git upstream-branch-name
git checkout branch-name
git merge --no-ff upstream-branch-name
git push
```